# ASP.NET MVC - Server error in '/' Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I could use some help with this.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Start/Movie/1

I really can't find where the issue is.

```
namespace IMDB.Controller
{
    public class StartController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Start
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //ViewBag.Title = DateTime.Now();

            var movies = GetMoviesFromRepository();

            return View(movies);
        }
        // GET: Details

        public ActionResult Movies(int id)
        {
            var allMovies = GetMoviesFromRepository();
            var movie = allMovies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MovieID.Equals(id));

            return View(movie);
        }

        private List<Movie> GetMoviesFromRepository()
        {

            var movies = new List<Movie>();

            var movie1 = new Movie();
            movie1.MovieID = 1;
            movie1.Title = "Terminator";
            movie1.Genre = "Action";
            movie1.Year = 1984;
            movie1.Country = "America";
            movies.Add(movie1);

            var movie2 = new Movie();
            movie2.MovieID = 2;
            movie2.Title = "Terminator II";
            movie2.Genre = "Action";
            movie2.Year = 1991;
            movie2.Country = "America";
            movies.Add(movie2);

            return movies;
        }
    }
}
```

I am probably just really blind and tired now. What am I missing?

Comment: The action name is Movies while the 404 indicates you try to call Movie. Looks like a typo.

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't notice that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`public ActionResult Movies(int id)`

should be

`public ActionResult Movie(int id)`

Comment: Wow, that's embarrassing. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

You have `StartController` and `public ActionResult Movies(int id)` method, but you call `/Start/Movie/1`. Notice the difference in `Movie` vs `Movies`.

That's the problem :)

Comment: Wow, that's embarrassing, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score -1):

I have 3 guesses as to the cause of your problem.

1. The requested URL of "/Start/Movie/1" was defined incorrectly.
2. The "/Start/Movie/1" folder exists, but it is empty.
3. The "/Start/Movie/1" folder does not exist.

Comment: This is MVC. There are no folders. Only controllers, actions and views.